# Creating patch using git diff for uncommitted changes shows a/.... and b/

Tags: git, git-diff

I am trying to create a patch for uncommitted changes in my workspace using command line . I am using following command to create patch

git diff > diff.patch .

This does create a patch but in the patch it shows diff as this

```
diff --git a/hedwig-client/src/main/java/org/apache/hedwig/client/netty/impl/multiplex/MultiplexHChannelManager.java b/hedwig-client/src/main/java/org/apache/hedwig/client/netty/impl/multiplex/MultiplexHChannelManager.java
index f28a6b2..3db2b7f 100644
--- a/hedwig-client/src/main/java/org/apache/hedwig/client/netty/impl/multiplex/MultiplexHChannelManager.java
+++ b/hedwig-client/src/main/java/org/apache/hedwig/client/netty/impl/multiplex/MultiplexHChannelManager.java
```

I want this a and b in the path not to be present  . So that it shud look like

```
diff --git hedwig-client/src/main/java/org/apache/hedwig/client/netty/impl/multiplex/MultiplexHChannelManager.java hedwig-client/src/main/java/org/apache/hedwig/client/netty/impl/multiplex/MultiplexHChannelManager.java
```

Any idea how to do this .

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a command line switch for that: `git diff --no-prefix`, but you don't really want to use `git diff`, you should do the right thing and make commits on private branches, and then use `git format-patch` to produce nicely-formatted patch series out of these (it accepts the same switches).

There's also `--src-prefix` and `--dst-prefix` to specify arbitrary paths. But keep in mind that, even when not using git, most people would use `patch -sp1`  or something similar... a prefix path is almost always expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ismael . This worked for me . I created a local branch . Added all modified files and then committed to that branch .Finally , git format-patch gave me nicely-formatted patch just as you said :)

Answer (score -1):

just modify the patch by stripping off the offending characters:

```
git diff | sed -e 's|^\(diff --git \)a/\(.* \)b/\(.*\)|\1\2\3|' > diff.patch
```

this will check for a pattern `diff --git a/... b/...`, split it into 5 parts (`diff --git`, `a/` `...`, `b/`, `...`) and leave out the `a/` and `b/` parts.